# getting an error using breeze - The 'structuralTypeName' parameter must be a 'string'

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I am going through John Papa's SPA course on pluralsight and I am running into error that say The 'structuralTypeName' parameter must be a 'string' while using breeze.  Here is the actual error that is being thrown

[image: error]

The code that is generating this error is metadataStore.getEntityType:

```
    function extendMetadata() { names
        var metadataStore = manager.metadataStore;
        var types = metadataStore.getEntityType();
        types.forEach(function(type) {
            if (type instanceof breeze.EntityType) {
                Set(type.shortName, type)
            }
        });

        function set(resourceName, entityName) {
            metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName(resourceName, entityNames);
        }
```

it is called by my prime function.

```
    function prime() {
        if (primePromise) return primePromise  //if primePromise was loaded before, just return it

        primePromise = $q.all([getLookups()])
            .then(extendMetadata) 
            .then(success); 
        return primePromise;

        function success() { 
            setLookups();
            log('Primed the data');
        }
```

I'm unsure what the problem is with the breeze call. Any insight into how to fix this?  Thanks for your help community.

Nick

Here is the lookups query info:

```
    function setLookups() {
        var entityNames = {
            personnel: 'Personnel',
            cto: 'Cto',
            kkeys: 'Kkey',
            promotion: 'Promotion',
            loa: 'Loa'
        };
        service.lookupCachedData = {
            ctos: _getAllLocal(entityNames.cto, 'ctodate' )
            kkeys: _getAllLocal(entityNames.kkeys, 'keystamp'),
            promotions: _getAllLocal(entityNames.promotion, 'pdate'),
            loas: _getAllLocal(entityNames.loa, 'lstrdte')
        }
    }

    function _getAllLocal(resource, ordering) {
        return EntityQuery.from(resource)
            .orderBy(ordering)
            .using(manager)
            .executeLocally();
    }


    function getLookups() {
        return EntityQuery.from('Lookups')
        using(manager).execute()
        .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed)


        function querySucceeded(data) {
            log('Retrieved [Lookups] from remote data source', data, true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function _queryFailed(error) {
        var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Error retrieving data from entityquery' + error.message;
        logError(msg, error);
        throw error;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: Hi PW Kad, thanks for answering back.  I added more info above.  I assume you was asking about setLookups and getLookups?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass in a string to getEntityType.  Sorry I missed that the first time through.

```
metadataStore.getEntityType('cto');
```

Also you are going to blow up when you are trying to call `Set()` function but the functions name is `set()` and also set is probably a keyword you aren't trying to override.

Comment: doh!!!. Glad you saw that set.  So I guess I'll have to iterate through all my entities.  The sample John Papa had     proto.getEntityTypes = function () {
            return getTypesFromMap(this._structuralTypeMap);         
    };  Now that you pointed out, my breeze has  proto.getEntityType = function (structuralTypeName, okIfNotFound) {
        assertParam(structuralTypeName, "structuralTypeName").isString().check();
        assertParam(okIfNotFound, "okIfNotFound").isBoolean().isOptional().check(false);
        return this._getEntityType(structuralTypeName, okIfNotFound);
    };  Thanks